# castle windsor service overrides for overriding default

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I was wondering is there is a pattern in Windsor for the following scenario.

Basically I have a service (DefaultService) that is registered, and have a plugin in which I want to replace the service (DefaultService) with (PluginBasedService) for all instances.

I'm currently using a hack - Kernel.RemoveComponent(), then re-adding my Plugin-based service.  This seems hacky.  IHandleSelector seems hacky for this scenario as well.

The Autofac approach of resolving the "Last Registered" service would also work for me.

Cheers, 
Chris

```
public class VM 
{
  public VM(IService)  
  {

  }
}

public interface IService {}

public class DefaultService : IService {} 
public class PluginBasedService : IService {}

Container.Register(
  Component.For<IService>().ImplementedBy<DefaultService>(), 
  Component.For<VM>()
  );

  // this is called in a dynamically loaded assembly, after the default service has been registered
Container.Register(
  Component.For<PluginBasedService>()
  .ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey<IService>.Eq<PluginBasedService>())
  );


Container.Resolve<IService>() // is DefaultService -> I want "PluginBasedService"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question (perhaps you could rewrite it, it's not very clear what you're after), but if I understand correctly, what you're after is to be able to use different component for a given service in certain context.

If that's indeed the case I think either `IHandlerSelector` or child container might provide a way to achieve that.

Comment: I've tidied a little.  I will look at child containers and see if they solve my problem.  Thanks

Comment: BTW, upcoming version of Windsor (v3) lets you force a component to become a default for a service when registering it.